# Augeas memcached edit via puppet

Tags: heroku, memcached, puppet, augeas

I am trying to make a change to my memcached.conf file via Augeas with puppet.  I have this in my manifest file:

```
  augeas { 'listen_on_IP':
    context => '/etc/memcached.conf',
    changes => ['set l 0.0.0.0'],
  }
```

but I see no changes.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (to mimic Heroku's Celadon Cedar stack as closely as possible) and starting with [a stock memcached.conf](https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/48dc5be438f5918258e7).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the output of `puppet agent --test --debug` contain any hints?

Comment: I'll try that when I get back to my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `context` is wrong. It should look like below:

```
augeas { 'listen_on_ip':
  context => '/files/etc/memcached.conf',
  changes => ['set l 0.0.0.0']
}
```

Take a look at [the augueas documentation](http://augeas.net/docs/tree.html) for more information on the `augeas tree`. (eg. `/files`, `/augeas`, etc)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This did not work for me.  I am beginning to suspect that my puppet installation is treating the augeas resource as a no op.

Comment: @Erik just to troubleshoot. can you supply the output of `augtool print /files/etc/memcached.conf/l`? If your using `Puppet Enterprise` then puppet's `augtool` would be located in `/opt/puppet/bin`

Comment: `which augtool` shows me that it's not installed.  I install puppet via this vagrant script: https://github.com/hashicorp/puppet-bootstrap.  I assumed augeas was installed like hiera is.

Comment: I'm not sure about that install script. Maybe the pre-reqs aren't met? `https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/augeas.html#pre-requisites`. What is the output of `dpkg --list|grep aug`?

Comment: $ dpkg --list|grep aug

ii  augeas-lenses                   0.10.0-0ubuntu4                     Set of lenses needed by libaugeas0 to parse config files

ii  libaugeas-ruby                  0.3.0-1.1ubuntu4                    Augeas bindings for the Ruby language

ii  libaugeas-ruby1.8               0.3.0-1.1ubuntu4                    Augeas bindings for the Ruby language

ii  libaugeas0                      0.10.0-0ubuntu4                     Augeas configuration editing library and API

Comment: I'm also running ruby 1.9.

Comment: appears that the install script didn't install or require those packages to be installed. trying `apt-get install libaugeas-ruby1.9.1 augeas-tools` and see if `augtool` is available after that.

Comment: No change.  Also, when I run `augtool print /files/etc/memcached.conf/l` I get no output.

Comment: I'm at a loss. I just spun up an ubuntu node, used that install script and the `augeas` resource in my answer worked for me. Sorry man. not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll keep pounding on it.  You've given me some things to mess with.

Comment: One more test. when running `puppet apply` on your manifest add `-v -d --trace` and see if there is anything relevant.

Comment: Looks like augeas isn't finding or parsing the file: https://gist.github.com/ErikEvenson/7628e2630c90299847da.

Comment: strange. that issue seems to relate to `https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/augeas.git/commit/?id=f81b2e44b15c0dc215eebd5632715ddfca4593a8` which apparently was fixed in 2012. sorry man. i'm dumbfounded. wish i could have helped more.

Comment: https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/augeas.git/commit/?id=f81b2e44b15c0dc215eebd5632715ddfca4593a8

Comment: seems when putting the link in a `'s it broke the link.

Comment: The memcached lens was [added in Augeas 1.0.0](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/blob/master/NEWS#L394), but Ubuntu 12.04 has 0.10.0, so it doesn't support it.  You could use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~raphink/+archive/ppa) or perhaps try installing [the lens](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hercules-team/augeas/master/lenses/memcached.aug) in your current version (in /usr/share or lib/augeas/lenses/ in a module if on Puppet 2.7.18+), but it may not be compatible.

Comment: @m0dlx that does seem to be the problem.  Working on getting Augeas 1.0.0 on my 12.04 box.

Comment: I tried using an Ubuntu 14.04 vagrant box and everything works fine.  I think I will just migrate to 14.04 now rather than later.  Hopefully Heroku's Celadon Cedar-14 stack will come out of beta soon.  Thanks for all the help.  I will post an answer in the next day unless @m0dlx or Petey T beats me to it.